# How do I get python scapy to sniff from a named fifo

Tags: python, scapy, fifo, packet-sniffers

I have pcap data being written onto a named fifo. I would like scapy to sniff upon that named fifo instead of an actual interface. How do I get this done?

Assuming that I have my fifo file as `/tmp/sniffme`.

The default sniff function call is:

```
from scapy.all import *

sniff(iface=<<NAMED_FIFO>> filter=filter, prn=uploadPacket(url, userToken), count=count, store=0)
```

I do not find any documentation regarding this, I'm under the impression that such a scenario isn't supported(?) Would appriciate some help regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

Hi,

This should work:

```
sniff(offline="/path/to/fifo", [...])
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Unfortunatly I'm running into - ```tcpdump: unknown file format ... ...  "Not a pcapng capture file (bad magic: %r)" % magic
scapy.error.Scapy_Exception: Not a pcapng capture file (bad magic: '')
``` 

Is this because it only looks for pcap files and not fifo?